# How long does it take for change in AWS Lambda to take effect in your published skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I just published a skill for Amazon Alexa. But the changes I made on Lambda side is not incorporated into the published version. I made the changes just before submitting for review. Should I resubmit for another review?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are not making any changes in developer portal, you don't have to re-submit it. So if can you can still edit the lambda code with the same ARN given in developer portal, then it should reflect immediately.

But a better approach would be to create a new version of your Lambda code when you submit the skill. Versioning will create a new snapshot of the code with an updated ARN. This way you can edit your lambda code without affecting the live version. And of course when you change the ARN in developers portal you will have to re-submit it.

Comment: Thank you Cicil. But I just cannot figure out why the changes are not shown on the published skill. When I test it on the simulator, it works flawlessly.